# Why didn't jHipster project get LazyInitializationException in Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jhipster, lazy-initialization

What is the setting that jHispster project use for avoid LazyInitializationException in controller?

My Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/citys")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<City>> getAllCidades(@ApiParam Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Citys");
    Page<City> page = cityService.findAll(pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/citys");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

City Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class Cidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    private State state;
...
// gets and sets
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a Spring Boot rather than JHipster option. The concrete property is named `spring.jpa.open-in-view`. It is `true` by default, which causes Spring Boot to register `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`.

Source: [Spring Boot properties reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

Answer (score 1):

[As jdubois mentioned](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/67)
This is "normal" with JPA, if you access a lazy relationship outside of a transaction.

Normally, you should use a service layer, with a transaction. For instance, the UserService class is perfect for doing this job.

the only two options we have left is:

Using the open session in view pattern. I don't like it, as it hides the problem from the developer: he should use JPA correctly.

Letting people use JPA correctly: that's why JHipster won't correct this issue. You have many ways to go around this problem, either by using eager relations or by using a transaction and a Spring service. That's how JPA is supposed to be used, and Spring controllers, in my opinion.